# Partial function with default argument that is being changed later. Should there be any difference between mutable and non mutable objects?

Tags: python

I am learning about partial functions in python. I read that when you are specifying arguments to run your functions with, they get "baked" into function the same as normal functions with default arguments.

Here is what I mean:

```
def multiply(item, multiplier):
    return item * multiplier


my_item = 10
my_multiplier = 2

my_partial = partial(multiply, my_item, my_multiplier)

print(my_partial())  # 20

my_item = 5

print(my_partial())  # 20
```

But I was also reading that it should work different when argument is mutable, here:

```
def multiply(item, multiplier):
    return item * multiplier


my_item = ['a']
my_multiplier = 2

my_partial = partial(multiply, my_item, my_multiplier)

print(my_partial())  # ['a', 'a']

my_item = ['a', 'b', 'c']

print(my_partial())  # also ['a', 'a'] instead of ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'] ?
```

I wanted to ask if, if I found a mistake or it was working like that with mutable object in previous versions of Python? I checked 3.9 and 3.7 and result is the same.

Comment: **No**. It doesn't work different **at all** when the argument is mutable or immutable. In *both cases* you *always use the same object*.. Immutable objects are simply.. immutable. They don't expose any mutator methods. *Assignment* never mutates. But if you *did* mutate the object, it would change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't mutating the object, you're reassigning the name, and the partial object still has a reference to the old object.

Try

```
my_item[:] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

to actually mutate the same object.

Comment: Of Course, that is soo rookie mistake, I am actually ashamed. Thank you very much for fixing my way of thinking. I redid this example for my notes to first use simple variable reassignment and second with actual mutation by appending another letter. Thank you